# jQuery $.post update not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-7

I can't get this update script to work in IE.  Works fine in every other browser.  IE tells me that the update was performed. However, it wasn't.  I've no more hair left to pull out..grr. BTW I've tried `$.ajax` and `$.get` too..still no luck.  I'm thinking it may have something to do with the `live` click handler.  Don't know...I've tried everything..(putting headers for no-cache, attaching a random number to the end of my url string)..nothing fricken works...blasted IE.

This is the `$('.save').live('click')` function I am using:

```
$(".save").live("click", function(){
  $.post("update.php", { cache : false, saveID : saveIt.value, saveMo : saveMonth, saveYr : saveYear, saveCtg : saveCt, saveThg : saveTh },
  function(data){
    if(data.success) {

      $(textareaThoughts).hide();
      $(saveIt).parents(".dirRowOne").find(".cancel").hide();
      $(saveIt).parents(".dirRowOne").find(".edit, .del").show();
      $(saveIt).hide();
      $("#dirConsole").html(data.message);

    } else if(data.error) {
    }
  }, "json");
return false;
});
```

Here's the update.php

```
<?php

  if($_POST) {

      $data['id'] = $db->escape_value($_POST['saveID']);
      $data['months'] = trim($db->escape_value($_POST['saveMo']));
      $data['years'] = trim($db->escape_value($_POST['saveYr']));
      $data['cottages'] = trim($db->escape_value($_POST['saveCtg']));
      $data['thoughts'] = trim(htmlentities($db->escape_value($_POST['saveThg'])));

      $id = $data['id'];
      $m = $data['months'];
      $y = $data['years'];
      $c = $data['cottages'];
      $t = $data['thoughts'];

      $query = "UPDATE //tablename SET month = '{$m}', year = '{$y}', cottage = '{$c}', thoughts = '{$t}'  WHERE dirID = '{$id}'";
      $result = $db->query($query);

       if($result) {
          $data['success'] = true;
          $data['message'] = "Update Successful!";
       } else {
          $data['error'] = true;
       }

 echo json_encode($data);

 }


?>
```

This is the JSON response:

```
{"id":"360","months":"June","years":"1990","cottages":"Cedar","thoughts":"Hello","success":true,"message":"Update Successful!"}
```

Comment: It does not perform the update in IE7. But it does in Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: Don't you just *love* making things work in IE?

Comment: @Matt Ball => no, I don't :)  I mean c'mon enough's enough already.  Just die IE..die, die, die!!!!!!

Answer (score 10):

I agree with the answer above. I've seen IE flake with AJAX requests, both GET and POST, when a cache-busting string is not used. Just append a random cache busting string to your URL like so:

```
    $.post("update.php?ts="+new Date().getMilliseconds(), { cache : false, saveID : saveIt.value, saveMo : saveMonth, saveYr : saveYear, saveCtg : saveCt, saveThg : saveTh },
      function(data){
...
```

and it should just start working in IE.

Comment: It looks like if you requested a page with a GET and you're now doing a POST to the same URL, IE7 just says "oh I just got that, why bother?"

Answer (score 2):

Finally!
I solved my problem which is because of  "same origin policy" and just raise in IE!:
I've just change the **URL** parameter from : **'http://mysite.com/api/'** to **'/api/'**
and it works!!!

hope it help some of you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the "return false". This seems to cancel the onclick event in IE.

Comment: I see. When you said that IE tells you that it performed the update, does it mean that IE executed the lines within the data.success block? And that the problem is that the data that should have been updated wasn't updated in your DB? If so, maybe there's a problem with how IE parses what you send to the POST parameters? That is, maybe you can try alerting the following: 
{ cache : false, saveID : saveIt.value, saveMo : saveMonth, saveYr : saveYear, saveCtg : saveCt, saveThg : saveTh }
Maybe saveMonth should be saveMonth.value (just like saveIt.value)?

Comment: Yep...it's makes it through the `data.success` block, and says the update was successful.  The var that I used for saveMonth is the value.  Weird stuff...some kind of caching problem me thinks.

Answer (score 0):

First things that comes to my mind is a caching problem on the AJAX request.  Try appending a random value (using Math.Random() or whatever you want) to the POST request and see what happens.  I always append a random value to GET requests to ensure the responses are unique but I'm not sure how about the POST request.

Also check out this link and see if any of it applies:
http://greenash.net.au/posts/thoughts/an-ie-ajax-gotcha-page-caching

Comment: I have tried all of these suggestions...nothing works.  Thanks for the info tho.

Comment: `POST` is normally not to be cached. Also IE knows that.

Answer (score 0):

At this point in the process I would set up a server side log and see what IE is actually posting and if it was actually posting anything, not much of a code hint but the code looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [link text](http://ajax.dynatrace.com) with turned on parameter value capturing for post mortem debugging. It is free so give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the base .ajax method instead of the post abstraction?

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options

Perhaps it's not detecting the datatype with the post method.

Here is an full ajax call that works for me:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "content_admin.asmx/UpdateFolderDocumentOwner",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{documentID:' + $("#did").val() + '}',
    error: handleJsonError,
    success: function() {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

to

```
<meta charset="utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging problems like these make sure you get some information about the error back. IE tends to be silent when something goes wrong, but there is a way to get an error back:

```
$.post("update.php",{data:"blabla"},function(){
  /*... stuff to do on success...*/
},"json").fail(function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
  /*... display the errors here so you know what is wrong...*/
  alert(textStatus+": "+errorThrown);
});
```

At least you know what's wrong and you can start searching more effectively for the right solution.