# jQuery ajax post with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post

I'm making a ajax request with post method using jquery(1.10). Everything runs fine but with IE(currently testing on 9) it always calls the error method(**HandleError** in code)

Here is the code :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'action.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'post',
  data: {var1: val1, var2: val2},
  success: HandleSuccess,
  error: HandleError
});
```

I tried adding cache false, adding some random number to the url but nothing worked. I changed the post into get and everything worked. What is the exact problem ?

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551001/jquery-post-update-not-working-in-ie) question, but nothing solved the problem.
I also checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941898/jquery-ajax-post-parameters-sometimes-not-sent-on-ie), which talks about keep-alive problem and I checked with **Connection : Close** header, but again didn't work.

I intercepted the http request which IE was sending and found out that Content-Length is 0.

So my question is why changing **post** into **get** solves this problem. What is the exact problem which I'm not getting ?

Comment: does it work in FireZilla and Chrome?

Comment: What is your data? You can do post result of `JSON.stringyfy({var1: val1, var2: val2})` (except on your actual data). And what does your HandleError function get for the error message thrown? Maybe a ParseError? Change error to `error: function() { console.log(arguments); }` to see what is coming in to the error handler if you can't see it with your function.

Comment: @PratikJoshi firefox and chrome are fine

Comment: @Cymen val2 is integer constant and val1 is text, stringify is not working either

Comment: @Cymen When content-length is 0, the request is converted into normal request which is used to parse the view and HandleError method receives that response