# Why IE can not fetch jQuery POST() result?

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, post

I have a combination of jQuery POST() function with PHP.
**jQuery:**

```
token = $('input[name=signin-token]').val();
$.post('controller/create-captcha.php',{
     signin_token: token
}, function(data){
     $('#captcha').attr('placeholder',data);
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['signin_token']) && isset($_SESSION['signin-token']) 
    && $_POST['signin_token'] == $_SESSION['signin-token']) {
    $rand1 = rand(1,10);
    $rand2 = rand(1,10);

    $_SESSION['captcha'] = $rand1+$rand2;
    echo $rand1.' + '.$rand2. ' =';
}
?>
```

This code is working well in both Chrome and Firefox. But IE can not fetch the result at all.  What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery $.post update not working in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551001/jquery-post-update-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: the problem is IE and the solution is chrome and firefox *SCNR* but seriously - what version of IE are we talking about? IE always had more problems with using defined standards than other browsers, which is the reason why almost everything written in JS or CSS needs a workaround for it. jQuery has many workarounds built in, but not for every version of IE

Comment: @Nordenheim, that answer did not solved my problem.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I am using IE v11 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Is this a cross-domain post by chance?

Comment: What do you see in the console? Add an error listener to the Ajax call and see if it is being triggered.

Comment: Please don't use this as a captcha, terrible idea. A matter of fact - **it does not help at all**. Take a look at Google Recaptcha: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html